# CSS Hover Effect on info-box but Distinct Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, siteorigin

I was migrating a website from Wix to Wordpress, and I was using LC page builder.

When it came to the infobox, I saw the wrapper didn't have any hover bg color, so I created it with custom CSS, but when I checked the Wix website again, I saw that the color changes only for hover on the wrapper but not on the button.

I used this CSS code:

```
#dslc-module-ff03d9andc .dslc-info-box .dslc-info-box-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: #cc8419;
}
```

Now, since the button is part of info-box, I can't only pick the hover effect on the wrapper (if I can, please tell me).

How can I apply the hover effect on the wrapper of 1 color and the wrapper color hover effect when I hover on a button? The other choice could be the hover effect only on the wrapper, but when I hover on the button, the wrapper returns to it's original bg color.

Comment: I would add some additional class to wrapper (.hover) when button is hover or the wrapper itself with JS. And constructed CSS based on that classes.

Comment: It is really difficult for me to parse your text. I understand English is not everyone's first language, and I understand that not everyone is adept at writing perfect texts - but please try to structure your text at least a little bit?

Comment: Please take the time to [edit] your question to include the [mcve] code in order that we can reproduce your problem.